# Installing laravel/laravel (v5.8.17) [ErrorException] mkdir(): Invalid path

Tags: php, laravel

Я только начинаю разбираться не судите строго.

Пытаюсь установить Laravel на XAMPPv3.2.4 командой:

```
 php composer.phar create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

Установил **composer** всё было гуд, я не понимаю в чём ошибка ведь я работаю на винде а здесь не должно возникать проблем с правами доступа или я что то не понимаю.

Comment: попробуй сделать через homestead, упростишь работу себе в 100 раз

Comment: homestead cool, но можешь попробовать и OSPanel (модуль Apache+PHP7+Nginx). Полет тоже нормальный для неспецифичных проектов

Comment: С xampp тоже всё в порядке... Вы где эту команду выполняете? Поставьте на папку права 777 и попробуйте заново

Comment: @InDevX, да, права 777 на винде)

Comment: @InDevX, я исполняю эту команду в phpstrom в папке проекта, C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel, каким образом можно установить  права 777 на винде?

Comment: @Ep1demic Говорите, там такого нет? Смешно, согласен) Если нет...

Comment: Пробуйте из обычной командной строки установить.

Comment: @Ercog на папке пкм - свойства - безопасность. Другое дело что тут не в правах проблема.. Через `laravel new` попробуйте

Answer (score 0):

Во первых я перешел на OpenServer и там всё заработало.  Но когда я попытался поставить предыдущую версию(я просто смотрю уроки по 5.7 не хотел путаться)там снова была ошибка, не знаю почему на сайте Laravel строка установки выглядит так create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "5.7.*" это не работает. Работает create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel="5.7.*" blog. Все спасибо за помощь)

Comment: Так вы не эту строку скинули в вопросе. Вам бы сразу и дали ответ. Эта строка не работает `reate-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "5.7."` потому что версия указывается до **blog** (это название папки, куда вы хотите поставить)